# Passing /Zm flag to msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, msbuild

i am facing intermittent issues :- `C1060: compiler is out of heap space` . why do we hit such issues?
As per the documentations :- [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1060?view=msvc-170) & [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zm-specify-precompiled-header-memory-allocation-limit?view=msvc-170) , with the usage of `\Zm<factor>` we can control the memory allocation.

As part of our build, I notice that we are not passing `\Zm` compiler flag passed. I cant in that build commands that `\Zm` flag is being passed. So if we don't pass it, What is the default memory  consumption happens ? If we want to use `\Zm`, we should pass it at linking stage or compilation stage? is it mandatory to pass factor value `\Zm<factor>` or we can just pass `\Zm` that uses 100mb by default as per documentation info in latter forum above?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Open the Project Properties, change 'Configuration' to "All Configurations", change 'Platform' to "All Platforms", under 'Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line' in 'Additional Options' add your `\Zm` option.

Comment: The documentation you link to, [/Zm (Specify precompiled header memory allocation limit)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zm-specify-precompiled-header-memory-allocation-limit?view=msvc-170), says "the default precompiled header buffer is 75 MB". Provide a factor > 100 to increase the buffer. Use a factor of `140`, e.g. `\Zm140`, to increase the buffer from 75 to 105 mb.

Comment: @vam You can take a look of my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

> So if we don't pass it, What is the default memory consumption happens
> ?

**The answer is it will be 75MB.**

evidence:

[Remarks of /Zm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zm-specify-precompiled-header-memory-allocation-limit?view=msvc-170#remarks)

[image]

If you just use `\Zm` without a factor, it defaults to `\Zm100`, which means it uses the default allocation, equivalent to 100% of the default buffer size, which is 75 MB. Therefore, using `\Zm` alone does not increase the memory limit beyond the default. To increase the limit, you need to specify a factor greater than 100, such as `\Zm200` for double the default allocation.

> If we want to use \Zm, we should pass it at linking stage or
> compilation stage?

**It should be used during the compilation stage, not at the linking stage, as it is designed to manage memory allocation for precompiled headers and compiled source files.**

> is it mandatory to pass factor value \Zm or we can just pass
> \Zm that uses 100mb by default as per documentation info in latter
> forum above?

**I think the answer is NO.** Because both add this or not add this may cause C1060 issue. You can take a look at this:

[How to fix C1060](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1060?view=msvc-170#to-fix-this-error-try-the-following-possible-solutions)

Comment: So just passing `/Zm`  without any factor and not passing at all would acts as same behavior ?  In my case , Should i need to increase the factor to 200 to resolve ?